# How to install Ubuntu on MacBook Pro as Dual Boot?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, macbook-pro

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 in my MacBookPro. I am running Mountain Lion in my mac. I want to run both Mountain Lion and Ubuntu 13.10 in My mac. How to install Ubuntu in my macbook without affecting existing data and OS with dual boot feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I  think [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Detailed_How-To)  link  will  help  you to dualboot `Ubuntu and Mac OSX`.

Comment: FWIW, [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/MacOSX) has a nice introduction for those still thinking about whether or not to dual-boot OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: Each MBP Model is gonna have its own little quirks/workarounds to get everything working. You can check this link for guides tailored to specific models of the MacBook Pro https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro