# What languages does Ubuntu support?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am planning to buy a (hopefully, inexpensive - I'm poorer than I used to be) Linux laptop to replace my Mac laptop.  I'd like to be able to write & compile/interpret programs in C/C++, Python, SQL, and R.  Does Ubuntu have/support all of these?

Might it be better to just buy a Windows laptop and then download Cygwin?  I'd like to get Ubuntu, but I worry about cost.

Comment: you could install ubuntu on mac, you don't have to buy anything, and you can install any programming language on it

Comment: @Wilf http://askubuntu.com/questions/151371/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-mac-os-x and http://askubuntu.com/questions/372951/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro-as-dual-boot and http://lifehacker.com/5934942/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-powerhouse-apple-hardware

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu supports C/C++, Python, SQL, and R for sure. Don't worry about this.

For R:

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base
```

For Python:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

You can write the code (Geani for example) and compile with GCC.
For C:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

For SQL:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Docs:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html
- http://www.r-project.org/
- http://www.python.org/
- http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: It would be nice to have some more info, plus some links...